# awk not printing expected result from file

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I expected that adding `NR==2` would only print check the 2nd line `$1` value, the `1` and ensure that it is a number. If it is then print `Index is a number` else
`Index is not a number`.  It seems close but the results is not expected... maybe I used the wrong variable?  Thank you :).

**file.txt**

```
Index   Chr Start   End Ref Alt Quality Freq    Score   HGMD
1   1   10  100 A   -   GOOD    .002    2   .
2   1   100 1000    -   C   STRAND BIAS .036    10  .
3   5   50  500 AA  T   GOOD    1   5   .
```

awk

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==2 $1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]/ {print "Index is a number"} ELSE {print "Index is not a number"}' file.txt
Index is a number
Index is a number
Index is a number
Index is a number
Index is a number
```

desired output

```
Index is a number
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that all upper case `ELSE` was an awk language construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==2 {print "Index is "($2~/^[0-9]+$/?"":"not ") "a number";exit}' file
```

- If you just want to check line 2, you have to `exit` after the processing
- If you need other Field Separator, add `-F` option

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like below,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} NR==2 { if (match($1,/^[[:digit:]]/)) { print "Index is a number" } else { print "Index is not a number" } }' file
Index is a number
```

you can of-course extend this to *any* number of lines by dropping `NR==2` or adding `NR>1` which allows you to skip header only.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and explanations :).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
awk 'NR==2{printf("Index is%s a number\n", ($1~/^[0-9]+$/)? "":" not")}' file.txt
```

The output:

```
Index is a number
```

---

`$1~/^[0-9]+$/` - ensures that the first field is a number